# How to set visible row counts in ListView

Tags: java, swing, listview, javafx, jlist

How can I have a `ListView` in JavaFX that wraps the elements when arrives to a specific number of rows/columns depending on the display `orientation`. In fact I'm searching the [setVisibleRowCount()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setVisibleRowCount%28int%29) method of JList in the ListView component. In fact I have a large quadratic space with quadratic components. I need the functionality of a list so I prefer not to use something like `TilePane` which will make me to invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I think you control the number of visible rows by layouting the ListView. Depending if it is placed in a Pane with static or dynamic layouting, the number of rows will be fixed or dynamic.

Comment: Or you mean sth else or it doesn't work! If you fix the size of ListView by setting min and max width it will never wrap the items! You'd better test it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot fully understand the problem you are trying to solve, but I my problem share a common base with yours.

I wanted to set the amount of visible rows (exactly **3**) in my [`ListView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html). The solution was to bind the list view's preferred height with the height of a reference point in the node graph. In my case, a [`TextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html) gave a perfect result. I can image though that the ideal would be to tie the preferred height (or with) to the height (or width) of a [`ListCell`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListCell.html) which is the thing that the list view actually contain.

I put this piece of code in my controller's initialize method:

```
Platform.runLater(() ->
        myListView.prefHeightProperty().bind(someTextField.heightProperty().multiply(3)));
```

Note that I had to use [`Platform.runLater(Runnable)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) because during the controller's initialization, the nodes doesn't have a height. If I bound the preferred height without postponement, then visual bugs appeared.